# Where are Crystal Reports margins set in VS 2008 edition?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I'm using the Crystal Reports built into VS.net 2008.

A template for a report on our staging server prints (to PDF) as expected. When I used the same template and data on the live server the report exceeds the right margin by approximately 1cm or so.

Does anyone know where the margin settings are kept per server for Crystal reports? I don't set anything explicitly in the code.

Thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, although am not sure why there was a problem between my seemingly identical systems.

Edit the report and choose Crystal Reports > Design > Page Setup. Then I chose Adjust Automatically and it was fine.

Comment: @Chris - Ah man. I just read the question a minute ago and was in the middle of typing an answer. Glad you were able to figure it out.